# How to determine if I should use repeatedcv or oob in RandomForest?

Tags: random-forest

In the trainControl documentation it said

> ""oob" (only for random forest, bagged trees, bagged earth, bagged flexible discriminant analysis, or conditional tree forest models),

However, I saw a lot if examples of RF examples and most of them used either cv or repeatedcv. How can I determine which one to chose ?